# How to get single post id when calling a function using shortcode in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to get the single post id inside the PHP function that was called by a shortcode.

Please help me to get the single post ID.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use [`get_the_ID`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/)?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried yourself to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ID of the current post, you can use the following code.
`global $post; $post_id = is_object( $post ) && isset( $post->ID ) ? $post->ID : 0`

Comment: Hi Raj, Thank you for your great work! You already helped me to solve my issue. i am really happy to get the answer quickly.

Thanks Again!